# Can somebody upvote of its own question/answer?

Tags: discussion, voting

When someone upvote his own question/answer is there any change occurs to its reputation?

Comment: "Someone can't vote their own post"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, a user cannot vote up or down on their own questions or answers.

They can vote to close, vote to delete, but not up- or down-vote their own contributions.

Comment: It's worth to mention user is able to accept his own answer to his own question. This does not give him +2 for accepting answer (as an asker), nor +15 for having his answer accepted. That's the only rep-gaining activity one can do for himself, but it was taken care of.